# License for Test Plans with Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: azure, azure-devops

If we buy a Azure DevOps User CAL on the classic way (without visual studio subscription) for the Azure DevOps Server 2019. Has the User the possibility to use the Test Plans or do we need an extra license for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a billing/product pricing question.

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question doesn't fit here. You can open a billing ticket with Azure (free to do) to ask about pricing.